# Forwarding based on Host Headers

Tags: iis-7, proxy, hostheader

I am trying to get around ISP limitations of 1 IP address.  Here is what I am trying to do.  I have two web servers running internally on my network.  One is my main IIS box that runs 4 or 5 sites and I just added a windows home server.  I have created a dns entry for it called home.mydomain.com and the other server reponds to www.mydomain.com.

My router is set to forward 80 to www.mydomain.com's server (192.168.1.3) so when requests come in for home.mydomain.com the request fails since www server is not set up to listen to that host header.

I would like to know if there is a way with IIS 7 to 'proxy' requests to home.mydomain.com (192.168.1.4).  I had tried setting up HttpRedirect in IIS but that does not work as I would have hoped since it sends back a 302 to the client with a name that points back to the main IP address and then a vicious redirect loop happens.

I am told in apache this can be done by having one server proxy for the other.  Can this be done in IIS 7?  If not does anyone know of a webserver proxy type of software I can use?

Thanks in advance,

Rich

Comment: Yes, apache can do this. It is called "reverse proxying" there.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "reverse proxy".  In Apache you can do this via mod_proxy.  In IIS, you'll want to try the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1712) package.

Answer (score -1):

[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) for IIS can also be used to do reverse proxing.

Yet another reverse proxy package is [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/)